# AWS Data Pipeline - Can we re-use the EC2 instance created during 'on-demand' pipeline activation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

**Question -**

Can I reuse the ec2 resource created during first on-demand run of the data pipeline in subsequent on-demand runs as well?

**Description -**

I have configured an 'on-demand' AWS data pipeline which is required to be activated many times during a day ( say 3 times within an hour ).

( I can not go with the cron or timeseries style scheduling since I have to pass different parameters to the pipeline at each execution)

In each on-demand activation, Data pipeline seems to create a new ec2 resource ? Is this the case?

Can I reuse the ec2 resource created during first on-demand run in other subsequent runs as well?

AWS Documentation provides the following information but it's not clear whether that applies to 'on-demand' pipelines as well.

> AWS Data Pipeline allows you to maximize the efficiency of resources
>   by supporting different schedule periods for a resource and an
>   associated activity.
>
> For example, consider an activity with a 20-minute schedule period. If
>   the activity's resource were also configured for a 20-minute schedule
>   period, AWS Data Pipeline would create three instances of the resource
>   in an hour and consume triple the resources necessary for the task.
>
> Instead, AWS Data Pipeline lets you configure the resource with a
>   different schedule; for example, a one-hour schedule. When paired with
>   an activity on a 20-minute schedule, AWS Data Pipeline creates only
>   one resource to service all three instances of the activity in an
>   hour, thus maximizing usage of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Data-Pipeline-managed resources. For this scenario, you would need to spin up the EC2 instance yourself and configure [TaskRunner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html):

> You can install Task Runner on computational resources that you
>   manage, such as an Amazon EC2 instance, or a physical server or
>   workstation. Task Runner can be installed anywhere, on any compatible
>   hardware or operating system, provided that it can communicate with
>   the AWS Data Pipeline web service.
>
> To connect a Task Runner that you've installed to the pipeline
>   activities it should process, add a `workerGroup` field to the object,
>   and configure Task Runner to poll for that worker group value. You do
>   this by passing the worker group string as a parameter (for example,
>   `--workerGroup=wg-12345`) when you run the Task Runner JAR file.

This way Data Pipeline will not create any resources for you, and all activities will run on the EC2 instance that you provided.